# string printed in reverse without reversing in the code

Tags: c, printf, character, constants, string-literals

I tried to print the string by declaring it via ternary operator. Instead of any error it prints string in reverse.

Can someone explain please?

I was expecting string to be printed as `even` or `odd` based on the input.

```
 #include<stdio.h>

    void main()
    {
        int a;
        char *num;

        printf("Enter a number: ");
        scanf("%d", &a);

        num = (a % 2) ? 'odd' : 'even';

        printf("Its %s number", &num);

        getch();
    }
```

Comment: E.g. `'odd'` is not a string. It's a multi-***character*** literal. `"odd"` is a string. C is not Python or Javascript, single quotes are for single characters, double quotes for strings.

Comment: `num = (a % 2) ? 'odd' : 'even';` - you're compiler *didn't* warn you about multi-character literals? That should be `num = (a % 2) ? "odd" : "even";` . Further, `num` *should* be `const char*` , and the final print should be. `printf("Its %s number", num);` - I suggest you rewind a few chapters in whatever text you're studying.

Comment: Moreover the standard definition of `main` here should be `int main(void)`, and, function `getch()` is not a standard C function in `stdio.h`. It's a non-standard library function possibly in Windows `conio.h` or old Turbo C. Please pay attention to compiler warnings.

Comment: You're supposed to get *diagnostics messages* from your compiler for this.

Answer (score 1):

`'odd'` and `'even'` are integer character constants.

According to the C Standard (6.4.4.4 Character constants)

> 10 An integer character constant has type int. The value of an integer
>   character constant containing a single character that maps to a
>   single-byte execution character is the numerical value of the
>   representation of the mapped character interpreted as an integer. 
>   **The value of an integer character constant containing more than one character (e.g.,
>   'ab'), or containing a character or escape sequence
>   that does not map to a single-byte execution character, is
>   implementation-defined.**

So in this call

```
printf("Its %s number", &num);
```

you are trying to output the address of the variable `num` as an address of a string that is you are trying to output a string but `num` does not point to a string.

You have to use string literals instead of the character constants.

What you mean is the following

```
    num = (a % 2) ? "odd" : "even";

    printf("Its %s number", num);
```